# will painting the case and applying stickers effect the cpu temperature?

Tags: pi-4, cpu, case

I want to paint or add stickers to my raspi case so it'll be more colorful. Is it ok to do that? Does it affect the CPU heating up? What other things do I need to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What other things do I need to consider? :**

Consider the fact that the RPi has a *closed-loop thermal management system coded in firmware* that limits the chip temperature by increasing or decreasing: 1) core voltage level, 2) clock speed.

If by, *"Is it OK to do that?"* you mean, *"Will it damage the RPi to do that?"*, the answer is a firm and fast **"No"**.

Comment: While true, I can't think anyone wants to ask "What's the easiest way to reduce the performance of my pi?"  But it is important to realize it won't be damaged by overheating.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't cover or otherwise obstruct vents
- Don't put stickers on metal surfaces designed to be heat sinks
- Paint won't matter on surfaces that are not heatsinks, and it is questionable if it helps or hurts on heatsinks (lots of complexities in that), but again, don't block (or clog) vents.

If your question is "will doing this hurt performance"...then the answer is yes it matters.